# Identifying Shower fitting

Tags: shower, fitting

I have a shower fitting I am having trouble identifying.

I assume that a standard shower head and hose are ½" even in metric Denmark  I bought this shower for which the valve to change from the main to the smaller shower broke off. I have found [a similar valve online with only ½" threads](https://dnk.grandado.com/products/1pc-3-vejs-t-adapter-messing-g1-2-tee-stik-med-omskifter-bidet-til-badeventilsprojte-toilet-bruser-brusebad-lukket-hoved-e0-l-4) but I would need an adapter for the last part which is bigger (¾"?¿)

Besides taking it apart and bringing it to my hardware store, how could I identify s similar replacement part? (The merchant does not provide information about spares, and I would like something a bit more sturdy)

[image: fitting]

[image: broken valve]

## UPDATE:

I took contact to the store's customer service, who could not provide the specs, and confirmed that they carried no spares. They did however give me the name of the supplier, and their product number. I wrote them, stating the issue, and they answered that they would send a spare part to me. Sometimes you get lucky...

Comment: Make sure you use the right thread gauge.  Pipe threads are different from bolt/nut threads and there are different types of pipe threads.  Usually the best bet is to go to your local hardware/plumbing store.  Usually the pipe size is the internal size, not the external size.  A 1/2 inch pipe might measure ~ 3/4 inch threads.  They never make it simple.

Comment: Glad you got this working, but please write up your "update" as an Answer, down below. That's how this site is designed to work.

Comment: If I get some details or a separate part number with the part, I will post an answer with those details.

Answer (score 1):

The two circled parts are (very likely) 1/2" pipe thread; this is *very commonly* used for both the standard shower arm and head connections and for hand-held shower hoses. **Note**, while they are likely 1/2 pipe thread (NPT) they are probably *not* tapered like normal pipe thread fittings are, because they use a rubber (or rubber*ish*) washer to effect a seal. This could cause problems if you are trying to find some other type of fitting as opposed to an exact/OEM replacement.

The other thread *looks* like 3/4" pipe thread, but could also be a manufacturer-specific/proprietary thread (because these units are not typically designed to be serviced beyond replacement of the hose and sprayer head).

I recommend you purchase an exact/OEM replacement; it will save you a lot of frustration and time and should last at least as long as the original one did...

[image]